# Closed bounded nonempty subset of R^2

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I found two sets that are both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}^2: \emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

And I also found a closed but not open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$B(0,1)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 :  \|x\|≤ 1\}$

Now I have to find a closed, bounded, non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
My thought was $C[0,1]$?

Comment: A singleton set would work.

Comment: So something like {0}?

Comment: Yep! That would work perfectly. You might want to write it as $\{(0,0)\}$ though since it's more rigorous notation.

Comment: Your $B(0,1)$ is not closed, by the way.

Comment: Thank you Cameron!

Comment: Also that's is a typo, my fault. Is it correct if the < is ≤  instead?

Comment: Why don't you pick $B(0,1)$ as well for the last example?